# Erase algorithm to be implemented using AS3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there any algorithm to perform erase operation in a bitmap? I would like to create functionality similar to how photoshop or other graphic application performs erase. Is erase operation so difficult that there isn't much help (for bitmaps) available? I am OK even with name of an algorithm, I can proceed from there.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a really nice solution for this here:

http://www.piterwilson.com/personal/2008/05/07/bitmapdata-erasing-in-as3-with-custom-brush-shape/

Comment: Thanks Tamas!! I am looking for an algorithm. I couldn't find an algorithm after googling for it.

Comment: J_A_X, I am looking for an erase algorithm for me to implement. I have already checked the link which Tamas has given.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase with a rectangular eraser, you could try accessing the bitmapData and getting some pixels. You can then change their alpha to 0, as shown in de the code below.

```
var myBitmap:Bitmap = //YourBitmap;
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
var myEraser:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);//Or some other values, depending on the x, y, width and height of your eraser.

for(var i:uint = 0; i < myEraser.width; i++)
{
    for(var j:uint = 0; j < myEraser.height; j++)
    {
        myBitmapData.setPixel32(i + myEraser.x, j + myEraser.y, 0x00000000);
    }
}
```